# How would you go about placing li in different divs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an input box that, when you type into it, creates a visible li with the word you entered on it.

I am trying to make it so that, depending on what the user types (either the number 1, 2, or 3), the placement of the li goes into the appropriate div (Div1 if they typed "1", Div2 if they typed "2", or Div3 if they typed "3").

And I really can't figure out how to achieve this. I can figure out how to make pretty much everything else change about it (the text color, the background color, padding, etc) EXCEPT for getting it into the right div!!

Can this be done through CSS or is this a jQuery thing or what?

Please give me ideas of where to go with this.

```
 <input type="text" placeholder="Type 1, 2, or 3 here." autocomplete="off">
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/d33v479h/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case, since the value of the input element and the the sufix of the div are the same, so you could just use that to add the li

```
$('input').change(function () {
    var value = this.value;
    if ($.inArray(value, ['1', '2', '3']) > -1) {
        $('<li />', {
            text: value
        }).appendTo('#d' + value + ' ul')
    }
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/d33v479h/)

Also note that you are adding the [li](http://w3c.github.io/html-reference/li.html#li-context) to a `ul` element not it a div

Comment: Problem is now completely solved on my project using your help. Thank you!